# How can I send an image using sockets to save in my NodeJS backend using just socket.io and multer

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I have an app where a user can upload some info and some pictures, as for info it's done easily using socket.io, but I'm having a bit of trouble with the picture aspect. I know there are third party libraries like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-file-upload) but to me it looks really excessive for something which is so simple if I just used a normal POST request. (Of course, if I'm wrong I'll be happy to use the library but just wondering)

So how I have it setup is on my server side I have it like this

```
// Socket IO Stuff
io.on("connection", function(socket){
    var upload = multer({
        dest: path.join(__dirname, '/public')
    });
    console.log("Socket has connected");
    socket.on("disconnect", function(){
        console.log("Socket has disconnected");
    });
    socket.on("component-submit", function(values){
        var tempValues = values;
        upload.single(tempValues.file);
    });
});
```

On my client side HTML I have a simple file upload

And on my client side JS I have it like this

```
$("#component-submit").click(function(){
values = {
  componentName: $("#component-name").text(),
  textValue: $("#text-area").val(),
  file: $('#file').prop('files')[0]
}
socket.emit("component-submit", values);
})
```

And in my backend I do get this object and there's something in the file value, but nothing's being saved.
[image: object]

Comment: Tried Sending the image as a buffer and decoding it like this - new Buffer(image, '7bit') ?

Answer (score 0):

i cant suggest that method tcp or websocket not proper way for file upload . Specially big files. Try http post method. But if you had to with this way , backendresponse.file.toString('binary'); with this your buffer convert to binary.